# How do you dynamically apply style to an element, type and class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to apply this style:

```
<style>
#elementId td[role='gridcell'] {
height: 136px !important;
}
</style>
```

But I need to calculate the height dynamically. How can I set this style using Javascript?

Thanks! in advance!

Comment: you need js for that

Comment: Is there some reason why you need to change the stylesheet rather than just setting it directly on the elements with `$("#elementId td[role='gridcell']").css("height", "136px")`?

Comment: What depends of your height value?

Answer (score 0):

**1) in css use of `calc` function.**

> Read more about `calc`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

*for example :*

```
#elementId td[role='gridcell'] {
height: calc(100%-20px) !important;
}
```

**2) in jquery.**

*for example:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dynamic = your calculate....
    $("#elementId td[role='gridcell']").css("height", dynamic);
})
```